# Convert multiple excel files into PDF files in python with muliple sheets

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.7

But how about multiple sheets with multiples excel conversion through code?

I did try code but it is only working for multiple Excel but not multiple sheets.

```py
from win32com import client
import os

directory = r"....directory path...."
for file in os.listdir(directory):
    file_name, file_extension = os.path.splitext(file)  # split file name and extension
    input_file_path = os.path.join(directory, file)
    output_file_path = os.path.join(directory, file_name + '.pdf')
    if file_extension == '.xlsx' or file_extension == '.xls':
        excel = client.DispatchEx("Excel.Application")
        excel.Interactive = False
        excel.Visible = False
        workbook = excel.Workbooks.Open(input_file_path, None, True)
        workbook.ActiveSheet.ExportAsFixedFormat(0, output_file_path)
```

Answer (score 0):

I have found a very useful method to convert an entire Excel document containing multiple worksheets into PDF. [Spire.XLS for Python](https://www.e-iceblue.com/Introduce/xls-for-python.html) will be used here to help us achieve this operation.
The sample code:

```
# Create a Workbook object
workbook = Workbook()

# Load an Excel document
workbook.LoadFromFile("C:\\Users\\Administrator\\Desktop\\input.xlsx")

# Iterate through the worksheets in the workbook
for sheet in workbook.Worksheets: 

# Get the PageSetup object
pageSetup = sheet.PageSetup;

# Set page margins
pageSetup.TopMargin = 0.3;
pageSetup.BottomMargin = 0.3;
pageSetup.LeftMargin = 0.3;
pageSetup.RightMargin = 0.3;

# Set worksheet to fit to page when converting
workbook.ConverterSetting.SheetFitToPage = True

# Convert to PDF file
workbook.SaveToFile("output/ToPdf.pdf", FileFormat.PDF)
workbook.Dispose()
```

Here is the complete article tutorial :[Convert a Whole Excel Document to PDF in Python](https://www.e-iceblue.com/Tutorials/Python/Spire.XLS-for-Python/Program-Guide/Conversion/Python-Convert-Excel-to-PDF.html#1)